# Facetgrid of PCA scores in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I have a tibble of PCA values where first column is the label. What I want to do is produce a pairplot of each of the the first two Principle components, a scatter plot of PC1 vs PC2 for each combination of categories (3 included here). Attached is a text csv of part of my dataset. I tried using ggpair but I couldn't figure out how to massage the attached data into a format that it would like, in part because it doesn't know how to ignore NAs.

```
p1 <- ggplot(irdf, aes(PC1, PC2,colour=Category)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_ellipse()
```

This code produces a scatterplot where the data are overlapping.

[image: Plot Output]

CSV:

```
,Category,PC1,PC2,PC3,PC4
120,A,-0.004010778,-0.001078139,0.002560689,-0.002477077
121,A,0.00137385,-0.003251322,-0.0012312,0.002884072
122,A,0.00137385,-0.003251322,-0.0012312,0.002884072
123,A,0.00137385,-0.003251322,-0.0012312,0.002884072
124,A,0.00137385,-0.003251322,-0.0012312,0.002884072
125,A,-0.005530058,0.000206478,-0.003651934,0.000106734
126,A,-0.005530058,0.000206478,-0.003651934,0.000106734
127,A,-0.005530058,0.000206478,-0.003651934,0.000106734
128,A,-0.005530058,0.000206478,-0.003651934,0.000106734
129,C,0.05459126,0.004348095,0.01402585,-0.001921671
130,C,0.005382812,0.004915268,-0.001480362,0.000944579
131,C,0.002448355,0.012424871,-0.008416275,0.000361269
132,C,-0.000936612,0.003991578,-0.001986253,0.001497678
133,C,-0.003822607,0.024979002,-0.009948887,-0.0015799
196,C,-0.020830672,0.015967276,-0.003338178,0.004129992
197,C,0.003977212,0.002084443,-2.15E-05,0.002564937
198,C,0.008799044,-0.009520658,-0.007143308,0.00033937
199,C,-0.003273719,-0.005096245,-0.001200353,0.00038518
200,C,-0.021442262,0.022713865,-0.011194163,0.000664158
201,C,-0.005399877,0.004867002,0.001075927,0.000930286
202,C,-0.001082562,-0.00174273,0.0030125,0.002118374
203,C,0.004913886,-0.006648075,-0.004697749,0.000364076
204,C,0.00141842,0.000320859,0.006396322,0.005044266
205,C,0.002011682,-0.00444237,0.000991321,0.00328382
206,C,0.003169989,-0.003892362,-0.001063221,-0.000253309
207,C,0.002139646,-0.006559916,-0.001683837,0.000612287
208,J,0.05459126,0.004348095,0.01402585,-0.001921671
209,J,0.003098164,-0.005939099,-0.00471109,-0.000507244
210,J,0.004762399,-0.005833026,-0.003249797,-0.000238942
211,J,-0.001493766,5.86E-05,0.002030541,0.001575403
212,J,-0.001501058,0.000437217,0.003820577,0.001316014
213,J,-0.002753525,0.000915653,0.001490557,0.00172809
214,J,-0.001670349,0.001603777,0.003935583,0.001931291
215,J,-0.001667739,0.000914704,0.001519535,0.000950852
216,J,0.002700166,-0.002849805,-0.005260336,-0.000976289
217,J,-0.002990762,-0.001229752,0.001240857,0.001728149
218,J,-0.001466045,-0.002434853,0.00041103,0.000900405
219,J,-0.002735407,-0.001136517,0.003169908,0.002208108
220,J,-0.001163076,-0.000313097,-0.001645696,0.000254576
221,J,0.001285879,-0.004654998,-0.001721707,0.000129652
```

#### Update

I did manage to solve my own problem but it feels ugly. The trick was to populate a tibble with all the possible pairs of scatters as below. If there is a less ugly way please could someone let me know?

[Good plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bC8wn.png)

```
    i<-1
joined_subset_full<-NULL
for (Cell_r in unique(subset$Cell)){
  for (Cell_c in unique(subset$Cell)){

    subset_df_c<- subset(irdf,Cell==Cell_c)
    subset_df_r<- subset(irdf,Cell==Cell_r)

    cell_c_tibble <- as_tibble(data.frame(Cell_c))
    cell_r_tibble <- as_tibble(data.frame(Cell_r))

    joined_subset_c <- cbind(subset_df_c,cell_r_tibble,cell_c_tibble)
    joined_subset_r<- cbind(subset_df_r,cell_c_tibble,cell_r_tibble)

    joined_subset_full[[i]] <- rbind(joined_subset_c,joined_subset_r)
    i <- i +1
  }
}

joined_subset_facet_tibble = bind_rows(joined_subset_full)

p1 <- ggplot(joined_subset_facet_tibble, aes(`Comp 1`, `Comp 2`,colour=Cell)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_ellipse()+
  facet_grid(Cell_r~Cell_c)
p1
```

Comment: So the plot is not the result of posted code but your desired result? How did you even generate the image?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I am missing something. But the code you gave is not separating the data into different facets. This is why you are getting all 3 categories overlapped in the same plot.

To separate in different panels, you need to add a call to `facet_grid()` or `facet_wrap()` at the end of your code.

You have only one grouping variable, so your facet plot would probably be a single row or column. The figure in your example (which I believe is what you hope to achieve) shows a 2-D grid but only the main diagonal has data. This seems like a waste of space...

If you had two grouping variables, then the 2-D grid would make sense.

To get a facet plot with a single column, you could use:

```
irdf %>%
ggplot(aes(PC1, PC2,colour=Category)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_ellipse() +
  facet_grid(rows=vars(Category))
```

[image]

The last command what you were missing. It is telling ggplot to create the separate panels, one for each category and plot the three of them in a column.

Now if you had two grouping variables, you could create a grid with the code below (here, I simply created another column called `cat2` with the same data as `Category`):

```
irdf %>% mutate(cat2 = Category) %>%
  ggplot(aes(PC1, PC2,colour=Category)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_ellipse() +
  facet_grid(rows=vars(Category), cols=vars(cat2))
```

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Apologise I made the image as an example of what I wanted but couldn't figure out how to populate. See my edit for the solution I came up with.